# Blend Tool With Variable Stroke Width Not Giving Perfect Strokes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, blending-objects

I'm trying to use blend Tool with variable stroke widthw but getting weird problem like this: [image: Issue]

Video I referenced is [How to Make a Linocut Look with Adobe Illustrator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCyE91-D-KI)

But I'm not getting same result as they got. I'm Using Adobe CC 2018 Version.

Comment: It works as expected here in CC2017. It's sort of impossible to answer this without being directly at the system and trial and error. There was a bug in earlier versions (sometime prior to CC2017) that made blends fail with variable width strokes. But that has since been corrected.

Comment: After some workaround i'm able to solve Problem partially, I'm currently using CC 2018.

Comment: i'll post detailed workaround here as answer, i hope it helps all.

Comment: It's also not impossible that the bug was *reintroduced* in CC2018. I'm jsut not booted into a system running that at the moment.

Comment: Checkout my solution, i hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Some workaround I able to do it properly.

Points I followed:

1) Grabbed Pen Tool and Draw Two Lines
2) Select Both and Apply Stroke & Variable Width Profile 1
3) Used Blend Tool by clicking From Line-1 To Line-2

It's Simple Solution that I was Not Able to know why it's not working when giving Strokes to both lines Separately.

Here is Workaround I Did..

[image: Solution]

If you noticed in **Problem** I was not able to blend properly as i selected both stroke Separately , Which later i solved in **Solution** 
I'm Not sure it's bug or workaround but this helped me